# How to do phpinfo on Gwan and php

Tags: php, centos, g-wan

On cent OS 6.4 , [GWAN](http://gwan.ch/) web/http server and php is installed.
created file 
info.php in /csp

```
<?php
phpinfo();
exit(200);
?>
```

gives header

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK =>
Server => G-WAN
Date => Thu, 05 Sep 2013 08:21:11 GMT
Last-Modified => Thu, 05 Sep 2013 08:21:11 GMT
ETag => "abc3657a-52283ef8-44d6"
Vary => Accept-Encoding
Accept-Ranges => bytes
Content-Type => text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length => 17622
Connection => close
```

and output as

```
phpinfo() PHP Version => 5.3.3 System => Linux torrent.ms 2.6.32-358.6.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu May 16 20:59:36 UTC 2013 x86_64 Build Date => Jul 12 2013 20:33:25 Configure Command => './configure' '--build=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--host=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--target=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--program-prefix=' '--prefix=/usr' '--exec-prefix=/usr' '--bindir=/usr/bin' '--sbindir=/usr/sbin' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--datadir=/usr/share' '--includedir=/usr/include' '--libdir=/usr/lib64' '--libexecdir=/usr/libexec' '--localstatedir=/var' '--sharedstatedir=/var/lib' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--cache-file=../config.cache' '--with-libdir=lib64' '--with-config-file-path=/etc' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php.d' '--disable-debug' '--with-pic' '--disable-rpath' '--without-pear' '--with-bz2' '--with-exec-dir=/usr/bin' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr' '--with-png-dir=/usr' '--with-xpm-dir=/usr' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--without-gdbm' '--with-gettext' '--with-gmp' '--with-iconv' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr' '--with-openssl' '--with-pcre-regex=/usr' '--with-zlib' '--with-layout=GNU' '--enable-exif' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-magic-quotes' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-sysvsem' '--enable-sysvshm' '--enable-sysvmsg' '--with-kerberos' '--enable-ucd-snmp-hack' '--enable-shmop' '--enable-calendar' '--without-sqlite' '--with-libxml-dir=/usr' '--enable-xml' '--with-system-tzdata' '--enable-force-cgi-redirect' '--enable-pcntl' '--with-imap=shared' '--with-imap-ssl' '--enable-mbstring=shared' '--enable-mbregex' '--with-gd=shared' '--enable-bcmath=shared' '--enable-dba=shared' '--with-db4=/usr' '--with-xmlrpc=shared' '--with-ldap=shared' '--with-ldap-sasl' '--with-mysql=shared,/usr' '--with-mysqli=shared,/usr/lib64/mysql/mysql_config' '--enable-dom=shared' '--with-pgsql=shared' '--enable-wddx=shared' '--with-snmp=shared,/usr' '--enable-soap=shared' '--with-xsl=shared,/usr' '--enable-xmlreader=shared' '--enable-xmlwriter=shared'
```

like plaint text no css nothing, how can i get regular phpinfo output ?

i am doing tests before migrating my php scripts over GWAN
can i use GWAN webserver without modifying my php scripts ?

Comment: its still giving output as plain text...no style nothing, and if i remove the exit(200) , it gives "The connection was reset" error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> G-WAN gives the output as plain text (no style nothing), and if i remove the exit(200), it gives "The connection was reset" error

`exit(200);` tells G-WAN to generate HTTP headers with the status code 200 (that's the G-WAN response HTTP headers that your question is showing).

If you ommit the exit(200), then G-WAN won't generate headers and your Internet browser won't know when to stop waiting for the server reply because the length of this reply was not specified (since there's no HTTP headers).

As a result, *the Internet browser* (not G-WAN) will wait and then timeout.

More details are available in the G-WAN FAQs and in the G-WAN PDF manual.

> But it's plaint text, no css, nothing, how can i get a regular phpinfo output ?

G-WAN is serving what your PHP script has generated.

This PHP script did not specify any HTML header, body and CSS.

According to the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php): *"phpinfo() outputs plain text instead of HTML when using the CLI mode."*

G-WAN could use PHP as a loaded module, like done for Java or C#, but so far our attempts failed to make the PHP runtime work in a thread-safe manner.

If PHP experts have special advices about how to make this work or if PHP publicly releases a new thread-safe version then we will be glad to give it another try.

Comment: I would not hold my hopes up for this, as PHP has never been 100% thread safe (except if you use the right configuration, which disables nearly all of the useful features). But if people really wanted, I don't see a reason why someone couldn't write a php _compiler_ from scratch, implementing only the most used features (after 5 years php experience it seems really easy to me to build a compiler, having done so in the past for other languages). Anyway, take this as an informational add to the answer ;)

Comment: Now i got the point, it was only php generated as its running on cli mode.... thanks, Is this possible to for GWAN to treat .html files as php ? i am thinking to use GWAN for production server.

Comment: Hmm... you certainly mean *"using files with mixed PHP and HTML code"*. Yes, this can be done, exactly the same way (put your *.php files containing HTML code under the /csp directory).

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible to treat *.html files as php scripts.

But i would  not use default PHP VM (as its not thread safe, as @Gil mention ), there are alternatives available though.

Comment: The (rather good) Mono/C# implementation might be the most complete and reliable (other "PHP compilers" only partially implement the PHP 'statndard') but we did not find any working example. Pointers?

Comment: PH7 is supported by G-WAN v4.11+ (and, being thread-safe, it's much faster than Zend PHP).